# Dynamically added fields in form not sent to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form that allows users to add more input fields dynamically to upload multiple forms

Form just looks like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
<table><tr>
<td>
<span><div id='attach_files'></span>
    <input type="button" id="more_fields" onclick="add_fields();" value="Add More" />
    <input type="file" name="attach_file_1"> 
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" align='left'>   
</td>
</tr><table></form>
```

The form tag is around it and the form submits perfectly fine with just the one attach_file_1, but as soon as more fields are added these fields are not recognized by the php file i send them too (while the attach_file_1 still works fine). 
For example

```
echo ($_FILES['attach_file_1']['name']);
```

returns the proper file name but

```
echo ($_FILES['attach_file_2']['name']);
```

doesn't.

I add the fields using the following code:

```
var files = 1;
function add_fields() {
 files++;
 var objTo = document.getElementById('attach_files')
 var divcreate = document.createElement("div");
 divcreate.innerHTML = "<span><input type='file' id='attach"+files+"' name='attach_file_"+files+"'></span>";
 objTo.appendChild(divcreate)
}
```

I've tried moving the form tags everywhere and have used the other post that's similar to this, didn't help.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your code is malformed. See: `<span><div id='attach_files'></span>` the unclosed #attach_files div

Comment: you use `divtest` but no `divtest` variable, did you mean for it to be `divcreate`

Comment: yeah it's all supposed to be divcreate